# Javascript debouncing and throttling on Window resize

Tags: javascript

Currently I have a handler on the Window object that listens to the resize event:

```
window.onresize = function(){
   doSomething(); 
}
```

And I'm now trying to write two methods. The first one should only allow the doSomething() to be called once every second and no more frequent than that, the second one should only allow it to be called when doSomething() hasn't been called for one second.

Can anyone provide me with a relatively easy implementation in plain JavaScript?

I understand that throttling is about limiting the rate a function can fire in a certain time interval, and debouncing is about ensuring that a function not be called again until a certain amount of time has passed without it being called.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Are you asking to explain the concepts or do you need this done for practical purposes?

Comment: For my learning purpose, I pretty much understand the concepts, but still not good enough to write the code myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here you go, fiddle exmple:](https://jsfiddle.net/fuxwxgLc/35/)

```
function doSomething(timer) {
  timer = timer || 1000;
  var alreadyFired;
  var timerID = null;
  var interruptCounter = -100;
  var fireLimit = 5;
  var fired = 0;

  function Debounce() { //Old way, how I understood you inititally
    if (alreadyFired != true) {
      alreadyFired = true;
      //Do stuff
      console.log("fired");
      setTimeout(function() {
        alreadyFired = false;
      }, 1000); // Debouncing on 1 second
    }
  }

  function ConstantFiring(firstIndicator) { // New way, as per comments.
    //Do stuff
    if (firstIndicator === true) {
      console.log("fired for the 1st time");
    } else {
      console.log("Firing constantly every " + timer / 1000 + " seconds.");
    }
  }

  function Throttle() {
    if (fired < fireLimit) {
      fired++;
      //Do Stuff
      console.log(fired);
      setTimeout(function() {
        fired--;
      }, 3000); //Throttling on 5 fires per 3 seconds
    }
  }

  function InterruptTimer() {
    if (interruptCounter === -100) {
      //This runs only the 1st time window is resized, if you leave this
      //part out, the function will only fire 3 seconds AFTER the first
      //event fired and then consistantly unless the event occured in 
      //last 3 seconds.
      interruptCounter = 0;
      ConstantFiring(true);
    }
    if (interruptCounter <= 0) {
      interruptCounter++;
      clearInterval(timerID);
      timerID = null;
      setTimeout(function() {
        interruptCounter--;
        if (interruptCounter <= 0 && timerID == null) {
          timerID = setInterval(ConstantFiring, timer);
        }
      }, 3000); // Interrupt timer
    }
  }

  //Change the following line to use a different function to test.
  var realFunction = InterruptTimer;
  return realFunction;
}

window.onresize = doSomething(768); //Add a parameter representing a 
                                    //period for the function timer (in milisec) 
                                    //This is very optional, you can also hardcode
                                    // it into the doSomething fucntion in case
                                    // you want to add some other event.[parameter].
```

**EDIT:** Would also like to add that using a simple Global variable as an indicator is a much simpler solution, less confusing, but less "clean" from a "proper coding" type of view. If you do that then you don't have to deal with closures.

**EDIT2:** Updated the code and the link to reflect the desired behavior from the comments.

Comment: Thank you. Also I'm wondering why in the last line we should write "= doSomething()" rather than "= doSomething"? I remember that in some cases when you attach an event handler, the parentheses are not required. Yet they seem to be necessary here.

Comment: The reason for this is because we are returning a reference to a function that we want fired. The `doSomething()` is not the function being fired here, it is the returned function. Basically the equivalent of what you would think of as `doSomething()();` It is a tricky one! :P The reason is because you do not want to fire `doSomething` everytime you trigger the event, instead you want the initial function that was "attached" to the handler to fire it's returning function, every time the event is fired.

Comment: Let me put it in other words, to clarify, as I was thinking this one might be confusing. At bind time, you want to fire doSomething in order to get it's result returned and bound, so you use the "()". If you leave it out, every time you resize you'd be firing doSoemthing, and you don't want that, you only want to fire doSometing once, and let it's returned result be fired every other time, because it's been bound to the event handler. Hope that clears it up a bit.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I have another question regarding the Debounce() function you've come up with. I assigned Debounce to realFunction, and let it debounce on 3 seconds. According to my understanding, debouncing on 3 seconds means that doSomething() will only be fired if the there was no resize event in the past 3 seconds; however this is not what I observed. I've tried to keep on resizing the browser window, and yet "fired" was logged to the console every 3 seconds. Does this suggest there's some issue with your implementation, or some issue with my understanding? Thanks

Comment: Oh no, the function was maybe designed wrong by me because I did not understand what you wanted. As it is, it should fire 3 seconds after it has last been fired.

If you need something to fire if there is no event in the past 3 seconds, that is a whole other beast. In this case I misunderstood you. Question that I would ask is, does that function need to the fire constantly, all the time, and get interrupted for 3 seconds upon event being triggered?

Comment: I'm not sure whether I understand your question... I think what I'm looking for is just that, initially, when the browser window finishes loading, and the user resizes the window for the first time, the doSomething() will be fired. After that, doSomething() should only be fired if the last resize event occured >=3 seconds ago.

Comment: Alright so first fire is triggered when the window is first resized, after that fire is triggered nonstop unless there has been a resize event within past 3 seconds?

Comment: Added the edited version which should work as you described, left the previous version in there just in case.