# why does addEventListener("resize") fires may times?

Tags: javascript

I have 2 files. I wonder why I get hi i+1 times. Let's say I resize window 1000times which is i=1000. Once I click window, I get 1001times hi rather than just 1 time. I have a small project that contains new EventHandler(), and I resize window 100times it lags a lot.How do I avoid this..?
By the way, this is the code pen
https://codepen.io/pen/?editors=1111

```
file-A

export.class SayHi{
  constructor(){
    document.addEventListener("click",()=>{
      console.log("hi")
    })
  }
}

file-B

import SayHi from "./file-A"
var i=0;
var sayHi=new SayHi();
window.addEventListener("resize",()=>{
  i++
  sayHi=new SayHi();
  console.log(i)
})
```

Comment: The `.addEventListener()` API does not remove already-added event listeners. It's cumulative; all the added listeners fire on the occurrence of an event.

Comment: Generally adding an event listener *inside* an event listener is a bad idea. Not always, but almost always.

Comment: This seems like a really good way to get a memory leak.

Comment: Why do you expect a single log when you did attach a thousand callbacks?

Answer (score 2):

The `resize` event does fire a great deal.  On most desktop machines, it fires every cycle of the event loop during the resize process.

Why? Because each resize is a separate event.

If you only need one event to fire after the resize has finished, you can look at debouncing or throttling the event.

[Javascript debouncing and throttling on Window resize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36544376/javascript-debouncing-and-throttling-on-window-resize)

Comment: "On most desktop machines, it fires for every pixel the window is resized.". Nope, it fires as part of the ["update the rendering"](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#update-the-rendering) algorithm (step 6), which is called only in painting frames (usually at 60FPS or whatever refresh rate the monitor is set to in Chrome). That's still a lot, but far from *every pixels*, ...except if you do resize really slowly.

Comment: Beside this previous nitpick, the rate at which this event fires is not the issue at hand.

Comment: Still not at every cycle... Steps 2, 3 and 4 of my previous link are here to ensure this algorithm is ran only in some very particular iterations of the event loop cycle: the painting ones. Basically, it will fire at the same rate as a requestAnimationFrame loop if you are familiar with this API.